# Ruby on Rails - Undefined Method - Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Unfortunately, our Ruby Developer is out of town, and we have an issue that needs a workaround fix until he can return. I have been tasked with finding it.

I am attempting to access one of our database views, hr_accounts_view, that contains the necessary data we need to incorporate into our existing page, which relies on an entirely different table. All that we are attempting to pull in, is the **Status** column from our view, so I have done my very best to keep the model/controller/view as simple as possible.

My hr_account_view model:

```
class HrAccountView < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = 'hr_accounts_view'

    include Savable

    # belongs to :hr_account
    belongs to :employee, foreign_key: :id


    validates :Status, presence: true



    end
```

Hr_Account_Views Controller:

```
class HrAccountViewsController < ApplicationController

load_and_authorize_resource

def show
    @HrAccountView.Status = HrAccountView.Status
end

private

end
```

I've also separated the view out into it's own folder within the views, in an attempt to make it correlate with the new controller. We are rendering this page within our general show page.

Page being called from our show, hraccountsview/_apptment.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     Status<br />   
         <%= display_text_field @HrAccountView.Status %> 
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I've gone through and read a ton of posts referencing this issue, and it looks like the issue would be a declaration in the controller missing, but I've tried all sorts of combinations. Unfortunately, the most I've really done in ruby and rails is minor page changes, and some search functions, but never anything having to add an additional table/view.

According to the error message, I have an undefined method 'Status' for nill:NillClass, and it is occurring on line 5 of my page that's being rendered. If I throw in a **rescue nil**, the page will at least display the header, but no data. The record being previewed has a populated record for the Status column presently. This is leading me to believe there's an issue with the model instead of the controller, but at this point, I've been spinning my wheels trying to figure out where the missing connection is at.

Does anyone have an idea of where I'm missing the connection?

You're help is greatly appreciated!

Rails Version 3.2.13
Database Version : SQL 2012

Comment: There's some swapping of cases going on here. Are \@hraccountview and \@HrAccountView supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: Is this new code? Or are you trying to fix existing code?

Comment: They are supposed to be the same thing. I didn't even notice that before I posted.

Comment: @zetetic This is new code that is being added to old code. We have a controller that is offering off of a human_resources table, but it doesn't contain the additional field that we would like to add in. We made a database view to tie these two tables together, and this is an attempt to implement that into the existing code. (hope that made sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few conventions that may help:

Attributes (the model version of a column) are specified in lowercase. So:

```
validates :status, presence: true
```

Same for instance variables. E.g.:

```
def show
  @status = HrAccountView.Status
end
```

I suspect that `HrAccountView.Status` may also be wrong, though possibly not. We would need to see what else is going on in the controller. Typically there is some operation doing a `find` on the model using a parameter value from the request.

The variable name in the controller and the view must match:

```
<%= display_text_field @status %>
```

In Ruby a capitalized string (e.g. `Status`) is a constant, a lowercase string is a reference to a variable or a method. If prefixed with '@' it is a reference to an instance variable.

Comment: This did the trick. By swapping the cases, it was able to pull back the necessary information, and is no longer throwing an error. I felt like I had tried that a hundred times already, but I must of had the cases out of sync somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`def show
    @HrAccountView.Status = HrAccountView.Status
end`

Unless I'm missing something, `@HrAccountView` isn't defined anywhere, so it's a nil object, meaning you can't access the property `Status` on it.  You should declare something into it first, such as `@HrAccountView = HrAccountView.find(params[:id])`.  This will load a single record from your view (if found) into your variable.